# Program Crash in Doubly Linked List Iterator print in C++

Tags: c++, list, iterator, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to run my linked list iterator to print the data I have entered into the list. It does manage to print all the entries, but as soon as it does, the program crashes. Does anyone see what might be causing it? I am running it on CodeBlocks so I don't know if that might be the problem.

It is the same project I've been dealing with in my other questions. Before I tried running the iterator to print the contents from the function inside the list class. However, the specs of the assignment don't allow the classes to trigger any error or control messaging within the report. The ideal is for the user to access the data completely. Anything like console messages have to be done in main. This is what I've gotten after tweaking it. Again, it prints the contents of the list successfully, but after that, the program stops working.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef string dataType;
typedef class LISTEntry* listPtr;

class DATAClass
{
    dataType key;
public:
    DATAClass();
    DATAClass(dataType key);
    DATAClass(DATAClass &dc);

    void setKey(dataType keyVal);
    dataType getKey();
};

DATAClass::DATAClass() {
  key = key;
}

DATAClass::DATAClass(dataType key) {
  this->key = key;
}

DATAClass::DATAClass(DATAClass &dc) {
  key = dc.key;
}

void DATAClass::setKey(dataType keyVal) {
  key = keyVal;
}

dataType DATAClass::getKey() {
  return key;
}


class LISTEntry
{
  DATAClass data;
  listPtr prev;
  listPtr next;

public:
  LISTEntry() {
    this->data = data;
    this->prev = nullptr;
    this->next = nullptr;
    };

  LISTEntry(DATAClass l) {  
    this->data = l;
    this->prev = nullptr;
    this->next = nullptr;
    };

  LISTEntry(LISTEntry &le) {
    data = le.getData();
    prev = nullptr;
    next = nullptr;
    };

  ~LISTEntry() {
  };

  LISTEntry & operator=(const LISTEntry &le) {
    if (this != &le)
        {
            data = le.data;
            prev = nullptr;
            next = nullptr;
        }
    };

  LISTEntry * getNext() {
        return next;
    };

  void setNext(LISTEntry * entry) {
        next = entry;
    };

  LISTEntry * getPrev() {
        return prev;
    };

  void setPrev(LISTEntry * entry) {
        prev = entry;
    };

  DATAClass getData() {
        return data;
    };

  void setData(DATAClass d) {
        data = d;
    };
};


class LIST
{
private:
    listPtr curr;
    listPtr head;
    listPtr tail;

public:
    LIST();
    LIST(DATAClass d);
    LIST(LISTEntry l);
    LIST(LIST * l);
    ~LIST();

    void addList(dataType n);
    void iterateInitialize();
    bool iterate_hasNext();
    bool searchList(dataType key);

    LISTEntry * getHead();
    void setHead(LISTEntry * h);
    LISTEntry * getTail();
    void setTail(LISTEntry * t);
    LISTEntry * getCurr();
    void setCurr(LISTEntry * c);

    bool isEmpty();
    bool isFull();
};

LIST::LIST() {
    curr = nullptr;
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
};

LIST::LIST(DATAClass d) {
    listPtr tmp;
    tmp->setData(d);
    tmp->getData();

    curr = tmp;
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
};

LIST::LIST(LISTEntry l) {
    listPtr tmp;

    curr = tmp;
    head = tmp;
    tail = tmp;
};

LIST::LIST(LIST * l) {
    curr = nullptr;
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
};

LIST::~LIST()
{}

void LIST::addList(dataType n) {
    DATAClass dc;
    dc.setKey(n);

    listPtr entry = new LISTEntry();
    entry->setData(dc);
    entry->setNext(nullptr);
    entry->setPrev(nullptr);

    if (!isEmpty())
    {
        tail->setNext(entry);
        entry->setPrev(tail);
        tail = entry;
        curr = tail;

        curr->setNext(nullptr);
        tail->setNext(nullptr);
    }

    else
    {
        head = tail = entry;
        head->setPrev(nullptr);
        tail->setNext(nullptr);

        curr = head;
    }
} //addList


void LIST::iterateInitialize() {
    setCurr(head);
}

bool LIST::iterate_hasNext() {
    return curr->getNext() != nullptr;
}

bool LIST::searchList(dataType key) {
    curr = head;
    while (curr != nullptr)
    {
        if (curr->getData().getKey() == key)
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            curr = curr->getNext();
        }
    }

    return false;
}

LISTEntry * LIST::getHead() {
    return head;
}

void LIST::setHead(LISTEntry * h) {
    head = h;
}

LISTEntry * LIST::getTail() {
    return tail;
}

void LIST::setTail(LISTEntry * t) {
    tail = t;
}

LISTEntry * LIST::getCurr() {
    return curr;
}

void LIST::setCurr(LISTEntry * c) {
    curr = c;
}

bool LIST::isEmpty() {
    return head == nullptr;
}

bool LIST::isFull() {
    return (new(LISTEntry) == nullptr);
}


int main()
{
    LIST * burger = new LIST();

    burger->addList("meat");
    burger->addList("pickles");
    burger->addList("onions");
    burger->addList("tomato");
    burger->addList("cheese");
    burger->addList("bun");

    burger->iterateInitialize();
    listPtr bgrIndex = burger->getCurr();

    while (burger->iterate_hasNext())
    {
        cout << bgrIndex->getData().getKey() << " ";
        bgrIndex = bgrIndex->getNext();

        if (!(burger->iterate_hasNext()))
            cout << endl;
    }

    dataType searchValue;
    while (searchValue != "end")
    {
        cout << "Enter an item to look up in the list: " << endl;
        cin >> searchValue;

        if (burger->searchList(searchValue))
            cout << "The item " << searchValue << " was found." << endl;

        else
            cout << "The item " << searchValue << " is not in the list." << endl;
    }

    delete burger;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Advice: stop hiding pointer types in type alises. `listPtr` is literally not helpful whatsoever, and adds obfuscation, not clarity, to your code. That said, `LIST::LIST(DATAClass d)` blatantly dereferences an indeterminate pointer `tmp`, which invokes *undefined behavior*.  Similarly, `LIST::LIST(LISTEntry l)` *stores* an indeterminate pointer value `tmp` into `curr`, `head`, and `tail`. What you do later with those indeterminate values is critical, and potentially invokes undefined behavior as well. *Turn on/up your compiler warnings and **fix** (not mask) what they show.*

Comment: So the crashing could be caused by undefined behavior in my constructors? I can just go and refer to them as LISTEntry pointers?